# How can I expose a .NET enum name to COM in the same naming convention as legacy C++ COM components?

Tags: c++, .net, com, midl

I have a legacy C++ component with enums which can be accessed to COM clients. For example:

```
typedef [v1_enum] [uuid(C04A9760-3555-1555-9555-0DA024B80555)]
[helpstring("Enum in C++")] 
enum myEnumName
{
    [helpstring("First Value")]     
        myEnumNameFirstValue
}
```

The COM client imports the library using its LIBID (guid) and can then use this enum as:

```
myEnumNameFirstValue
```

But if you defined this same enum in C#

```
enum myEnumName
{
   FirstValue
}
```

COM clients would refer to this as:

```
myEnumName_FirstValue
```

And .NET clients would refer to this as:

```
myEnumName.FirstValue
```

Thing is.. I'm trying to build a .NET component to "trick" COM clients into using it as if it's the legacy C++ component. And though I can create classes and methods that these clients "fall for", I can't do it with enums!

Is there any way to define an enum in .NET and override the exposed COM name? i.e. instead of name_value it exposes namevalue?

Comment: The naming convention cannot be changed.  You'd have to this the same way you'd do it if you target .NET Core, create the type library from IDL.  Already having the IDL from the old project ought to give you a good head-start.  Use C# only to implement the coclasses, with the extra detail that you have to use the [Guid] attribute so they'll have the same CLSID as the old ones.  [assembly::Guid] to match the old LIBID.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I've managed to create a TLB from the IDL, but when I try to import it to a .NET project (to implement) it fails to allow the TLB to be added as a reference. Does the TLB need registering? I've use tlbimp to generate a DLL from the TLB, which I can then import and implement in .NET - fine. Then I regasm my .NET dll which generates a TLB. And my COM client can access these implementations. But the enums still don't appear to be defined/available in the COM client. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Actually it's weirder than that. Some enums are exported and some aren't, no pattern to it - literally two enums defined next to each other in the IDL and only one of them is available. And even then it seems the COM client can only reference it using the "_" between name and value

Comment: Ok - I see.. I've not defined all the classes yet, so only the enums used by the classes I've defined have actually been exported in the regasm output TLB. Makes sense. But still the "_" appears to be required for the COM client to use it (i.e. name_value). Any way around this naming convention?

Comment: Only the types declared or used inside the *library* statement are exported to the TLB.  So yes, defining the coclasses is important.  The client code needs to use the TLB generated from the IDL, not the one generated by regasm.exe /tlb.  It won't hurt to compare them btw (OleView.exe, File > View TypeLib), they should match exactly so it becomes a drop-in replacement, other than the typename for enums.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not sure how I can expose the existing COM client to the IDL generated TLB (for enums) at the same time as registring the REGASM TLB for the implementation. The REGASM TLB has the namespace prefix (which won't work with the clients)

typedef [uuid(...), version(1.0)    ,
      custom(..., "MY_LIB.MyEnum")    
]
    enum {
        MyEnum_valueName = 0,

I need just "valueName" for the COM cliemts to be able to reference those enums. But when they use a class I need the implemention to be my new .NET code

Comment: Just found a reference to some advice you gave about how to get back regtlibv12.exe and I've used that to register the IDL TLB. And looks like the enums work! AND it's using my REGASM registered assembly code! Awesome!!